# Проверка данных с интернета в фоновом режиме

Tags: android

Какие методы нужно использовать, что заставить приложение в фоновом режиме проверять данные с интернета каждые n часов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно как то так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 3600000,  3600000, pendingIntent)
```

Так будет каждый час стартовать сервис myService. И в этом сервисе проверяй данные из интернета.

Answer (score 3):

1. нужно подписаться на событие запуска девайса для запуска задачи каждые n часов.
2. в главной активити сделать тоже самое.
3. при запуске п1 и п2, используя `AlarmManager` посылать интенты для своего ресивера.
4. В этом ресивере запускать `IntentService` и в нём лезть в инет.